# Finding all div elements with varying id value with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

This question must be a duplicate, but for the sake of it, I can't find it anywhere.

```py
html = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="7471292"></div>
<div id="5235252"></div>
<div href="/some/link/"></div>
<div id="7567327"></div>
<div id="1231312"></div>
<div class="card d-inline-block iteml_card elems3 section1 featured0 wished0"</div>
<div id="2342424"></div>
</body>
</html>
"""

#Create soup from html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I want the following output:

```html
[<div id="7471292"></div>,
 <div id="5235252"></div>,
 <div id="7567327"></div>,
 <div id="1231312"></div>,
 <div id="2342424"></div>]
```

We can do something like:

```py
soup.find_all("div")
```

but this will return all `div`s. If we want to specify an `id` attractor, we have to fill in a concise value as well, seemingly rendering it useless:

```py
soup.find_all('div', {'id': ""})
```

Comment: Your desired output is not correct, I think. You have a duplicate of `<div id="2342424"></div>` in your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### What happens?

You are close to your goal - But `soup.find_all('div', {'id': ""})` would be interpreted as an empty or non-existent attribute `id`, that is why you wont get your expected `ResultSet`.

##### How to fix?

It is not much to do and it do not really need a `regex` in your case, just use the [keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) and set your attribute to be `True`:

```
soup.find_all('div', id=True)
```

with dict syntax:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'id':True})
```

Or the equivalent `css selector`:

```
soup.select('div[id]')
```

#### Example

```
html = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="7471292"></div>
<div id="5235252"></div>
<div href="/some/link/"></div>
<div id="7567327"></div>
<div id="1231312"></div>
<div class="card d-inline-block iteml_card elems3 section1 featured0 wished0"</div>
<div id="2342424"></div>
</body>
</html>
"""

#Create soup from html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find_all('div', {'id':True})
```

#### Output

```
[<div id="7471292"></div>,
 <div id="5235252"></div>,
 <div id="7567327"></div>,
 <div id="1231312"></div>,
 <div id="2342424"></div>]
```

Comment: soup.find_all('div', {'id':True}) is a beautiful solution, should have tried that. Strange I have not found it in any documentation. Thank you :)!

Comment: Happy to help - Added a link to the docs, it still talk about  [`keyword arguments`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) but as often it could not cover all use cases and yes it is not that easy to find in this context. So I also learned something today, so it do not need the dict `soup.find_all('div', id=True)`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a combination of regex and soup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="7471292"></div>
<div id="5235252"></div>
<div href="/some/link/"></div>
<div id="7567327"></div>
<div id="1231312"></div>
<div class="card d-inline-block iteml_card elems3 section1 featured0 wished0"</div>
<div id="2342424"></div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile("\d+")})
```

##### Output

```
[<div id="7471292"></div>,
 <div id="5235252"></div>,
 <div id="7567327"></div>,
 <div id="1231312"></div>,
 <div id="2342424"></div>]
```

If you are interested in having the `div` tags whose id contains number, letters or combination of both, instead of using `(\d+)` try using `([\d\w]+)`.

Comment: This worked, irrespective of the fact there can also be letters or number/letter combinations in my div such as item53924112, therefore a strong solution :)! Can you explain what re.compile("\d+") creates?

Comment: @Rivered Glad to help. It compiles a regular expression pattern. If you are interested in having both characters as well, as I mentioned in the answer, you can use `re.compile("[\d\w]+")` instead of `re.compile("\d+")`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a lambda function that checks whether the `id` contains only contains numbers. A regular expression is overkill here.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find_all("div", id=lambda x: x is not None and x.isnumeric()))
```

This outputs:

```html
[<div id="7471292"></div>, <div id="5235252"></div>,
<div id="7567327"></div>, <div id="1231312"></div>, <div id="2342424"></div>]
```

Comment: Pretty sure a CSS selector `soup.select("div[id]")` would work as well in this specific case, to select all divs with ids.

Comment: Thanks, and what if id can contain numbers, letters or combination of both?

Comment: You could use `.isalnum()` rather than `.isnumeric()`.

Comment: @Paul M. This solution works fine indeed, you could add it since it is a strong answer